# Proving linear bijection of vector space mapping.

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing

As the title states above, I am trying to show that if $T : U \rightarrow V $ is a linear bijection, then $T^{-1} : V \rightarrow U$ is also a linear bijection where U and V are vector spaces.

Representing $U = \lbrace u_1, u_2, u_3...,u_n \rbrace $ and $V = \lbrace v_1, v_2, v_3,....,v_n\rbrace$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, I understand that the bijectivity of T means that each vector in $U$ will map onto only one vector of $V$ (as the assumption suggests). However I do not how I can translate this knowledge to $T^{-1}$.

Thank you in advance (I am new to proofs).

Comment: The duplicate does mot address bijectivity of the inverse.

Comment: How do you define $T^{-1}$? Remind yourself of its construction (which uses that $T$ itself is bijective) and proceed as always. For surjectivity pick some $u\in U$ and construct a $v\in V$ such that $T^{-1}(v) = u$. For injectivity assume $T^{-1}(v_1) = T^{-1}(v_2)$  and show that $v_1 = v_2$.